# Rigging and skin modifier using rigify modifier

Tags: rigging

[image][image]Help solve the problem with clothes. He visited different methods but does not help. weight transfer and self-painting did not help. How to get rid of a problem**enter image description here**

Answer (score 0):

I guess the different mesh parts are from different objects?

First, make sure every object has its scale and rotation applied using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → Apply Scale / Apply Rotation. Scale influences directly the rigs' deformation (basically as a multiplier), so if there are some differences in scales and rotation between the objects controlled by the same rig, it will be messy.

Then, the only thing you can do is work the weights so that the weights are basically the same where two different meshes hover each other or are close together. The goal is to make them move at the same rate, so if you set each close vertex with the same weight for the same bones, and if there's not a huge difference in mesh topology, it should work fine.

Alternatively, you can completely avoid the issue by simply joining these meshes together so there's not gap to manage in the first place.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE RESPONSE, BUT EVERYONE DOESN'T WORK NORMALLY.CAN THERE ANOTHER OTHER OPTIONS?

Comment: No, and writing in full caps will not help. Nor just saying "it doesn't work". You need to detail more the issues. Or gives us the file so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: Sorry for the capital letters. I can give you 2 different files, so that you could see what’s wrong with me. I will be very grateful for any help Give mail where you can drop the archive

Comment: No need for an e-mail. Just save your file with compression enabled, send it there : https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ And share the link.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=AYRw0d0z" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/AYRw0d0z/)

Comment: Help really need help. And such a rig can then be used for games in Unity and Unreal Engine?

Comment: On the file you gave me, scales and rotations aren't applied and weights are not corrected as I suggested. So I'm not sure if you did what I recommended and encountered another issue, or if you simply have not properly done or not at all what I recommended. How do we go from there? Also your rig isn't generated properly, some bones are imprecisely placed in your metarig i.e. shoulders or neck off center, but most importantly the foot bones should be in the middle of the ankles. So unparent the rig, correct the scales & rotations, then metarig, then regenerate the rig and work on the weights.

Comment: Of course if you have any issue doing all that you can tell us, so we can help. Once you're done, if there's still an issue, post your file again.
You might want to check some tutorials like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k
Or Rigify's manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html

Comment: Thank you, but nothing works, again finds one part on another. Applied  Apply Scale / Apply Rotation. I can’t understand what am I doing wrong ??